# Create Multi-Index empty DataFrame to join with main DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Suppose that I have a dataframe which can be created using code below

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'date':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-05','2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-05'],
                          'product':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                          'price':[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
                         }
                 )
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

I want to create an empty dataframe let's say `main_df` which will contain all dates between `df.date.min()` and `df.date.max()` for each `product` and on days where values in `nan` I want to `ffill` and `bfill` for remaning. The resulting dataframe would be as below:

```
+------------+---------+-------+
|    date    | product | price |
+------------+---------+-------+
| 2021-01-01 | A       |    10 |
| 2021-01-02 | A       |    20 |
| 2021-01-03 | A       |    20 |
| 2021-01-04 | A       |    20 |
| 2021-01-05 | A       |    30 |
| 2021-01-01 | B       |    40 |
| 2021-01-02 | B       |    40 |
| 2021-01-03 | B       |    50 |
| 2021-01-04 | B       |    50 |
| 2021-01-05 | B       |    60 |
+------------+---------+-------+
```

Comment: You would like to only keep dates that are between the max and min dates of each group, so how come they are still included in your desired output?

Comment: It is your assumption that I want to keep `min` and `max` of each group. As stated in OP `df.date.min()` is global `min` similarly `df.date.max()` is global `max`

Comment: Does `df.date.min()` computes `min` date for each group?

Comment: "Between" means boundary values inclusive. NOT "Exclusive". The resulting output is shown to be clear on what is required not to argue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249741/discussion-between-lopez-and-anoushiravan-r).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**

make pivot table, upsampling by `asfreq` and fill null

```
df.pivot_table('price', 'date', 'product').asfreq('D').ffill().bfill()
```

output:

```
product     A       B
date        
2021-01-01  10.0    40.0
2021-01-02  20.0    40.0
2021-01-03  20.0    50.0
2021-01-04  20.0    50.0
2021-01-05  30.0    60.0
```

**Second**

`stack` result and so on (include full code)

```
(df.pivot_table('price', 'date', 'product').asfreq('D').ffill().bfill()
 .stack().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'price'})
 .sort_values('product').reset_index(drop=True))
```

output:

```
    date        product price
0   2021-01-01  A       10.0
1   2021-01-02  A       20.0
2   2021-01-03  A       20.0
3   2021-01-04  A       20.0
4   2021-01-05  A       30.0
5   2021-01-01  B       40.0
6   2021-01-02  B       40.0
7   2021-01-03  B       50.0
8   2021-01-04  B       50.0
9   2021-01-05  B       60.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'date':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-05','2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-06'],
                                'product':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                                'price':[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
                               }
                       )
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df
# Out: 
#          date product  price
# 0  2021-01-01       A     10
# 1  2021-01-02       A     20
# 2  2021-01-05       A     30
# 3  2021-01-02       B     40
# 4  2021-01-03       B     50
# 5  2021-01-06       B     60




df.set_index("date").groupby("product")["price"].resample("d").ffill().reset_index()
# Out: 
#   product       date  price
# 0       A 2021-01-01     10
# 1       A 2021-01-02     20
# 2       A 2021-01-03     20
# 3       A 2021-01-04     20
# 4       A 2021-01-05     30
# 5       B 2021-01-02     40
# 6       B 2021-01-03     50
# 7       B 2021-01-04     50
# 8       B 2021-01-05     50
# 9       B 2021-01-06     60
```

See the rows that have been filled by `ffill`:

```
df.set_index("date").groupby("product")["price"].resample("d").mean()
# Out: 
# product  date      
# A        2021-01-01    10.0
#          2021-01-02    20.0
#          2021-01-03     NaN
#          2021-01-04     NaN
#          2021-01-05    30.0
# B        2021-01-02    40.0
#          2021-01-03    50.0
#          2021-01-04     NaN
#          2021-01-05     NaN
#          2021-01-06    60.0
# Name: price, dtype: float64
```

Note that by grouping by product before resampling and filling the empty slots, you can have different ranges (from min to max) for each product (I modified the data to showcase this).